# How can I write this loop?

Tags: r

I have five dataframes (a-f), each of which has a column 'nq'. I want to find the max, min and average of the nq columns

```
classes <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
for (i in classes){
format(max(i$nq), scientific = TRUE)
format(min(i$nq), scientific = TRUE)
format(mean(i$nq), scientific = TRUE)
}
```

But the code is not working. Can you please help?

Comment: Where is the rest of your code with the `data.frame`s?

Comment: In your loop, `i` is just a character and doesn't have attribute `nq`, you need to iterate through something like a list of data frames instead.

Comment: Your question is not reproducible and it is unclear (at least for me) what you asking. Please provide couple of data frames and desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a character value as a data.frame name. The value "a" is not the same as the data.frame `a`.

You probably shouldn't have a bunch of data.frames lying around. You probably want to have them all in a list. Then you can lapply over them to get results.

```
mydata <- list(
  a = data.frame(nq=runif(10)),
  b = data.frame(nq=runif(10)),
  c = data.frame(nq=runif(10)),
  d = data.frame(nq=runif(10))
)
```

then you can do

```
lapply(mydata, function(x) 
    format(c(max(x$nq), min(x$nq), mean(x$nq)), scientific = TRUE)
)
```

to get all the values at once.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is because 'i' is a character/string. As already mentioned by Mr.Flick you have to make it into a list.
Alternatively, you instead of writing i$nq in your loop you can write get(i)$nq. The get() function will search the workspace for an object by name and it will return the object itself. However, this is not as clean as making it into a list and using lapply.

Comment: More specifically, the right hack for OP is `format(eval((parse(text=paste("max(",eval(i),"$DF)",sep="")))), scientific = TRUE)`